# Parse HTML string into JSON in swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

I am working with javascript to display string using HTML to WKWebView

Call Javascript function in my View Controller

```
myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("customMessageWithDictionary('\(self.jsonString)','\(strTestType)')") {
            (id, error) in
            print(error ?? "")
        }
```

**In HTML file**

```
function customMessageWithDictionary(nameDetails,testType1) {

        nameDetails = nameDetails.replace(/\\/g, '');
        questionList = $.parseJSON(nameDetails);
        var iterator=0
        for (iterator = 0; iterator < questionList.length; iterator++)
            questionList[iterator].UserGivenAnswerId= null;

        questionObj = questionList[positionObj];
        testType=testType1;

        loadQuestions(true);
    }
```

If there is an HTML Tags in **jsonString** so fetch the error and my Javascript not run. So WKWebview is not displaying the content.

Give me the solution if HTML tag is in my jsonString so load javascript function using HTML string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: self.aryOfQuestionList,options: .prettyPrinted ),

let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) 
{
   print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")

   self.jsonString = (theJSONText as AnyObject) as! String
}

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=<\\w{1,40})\\s[^>]+(?=>)", options: .caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.jsonString.count)
let htmlWithoutInlineAttributes = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self.jsonString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")

 print(htmlWithoutInlineAttributes)
```

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve URLs for application resources, you should use URLForResource method of NSBundle class.

Swift 2

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("privacy", withExtension:"html")
```

Swift 3

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "privacy", withExtension: "html")
```

Comment: My HTML file is load succesfully but when i called myWebView.evaluateJavaScript method using JSON string so there will be an error if string contain HTML tag.

Comment: have you checked your HTML tags? is it properly opened and closed?